# Alert in UILocalNotification is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

`AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
[self.settings showReminderAlert:reminderText];
NSLog(@"Application REcieved Local Notification");
}
```

`ViewController.m`

```
-(void)showReminderAlert:(NSString *)text{
NSLog(@"Alert Called");
UIAlertView *reminderAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:text delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[reminderAlert show];
[reminderAlert release];
}
```

I want my application to show an alert when the users enters back in to the `application.app` `didReceiveLocalNotification` is getting called but the Alert method is not getting called.

Comment: What is the use of text in -(void)showReminderAlert:(NSString *)text ??? its not used at all

Comment: What is the use of text in -(void)showReminderAlert:(NSString *)text ??? its not used at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showReminderAlert:` in another view controller right? May be the object self.settings(object of that view controller) get releases when re opening the app. Try the alert in the appDelegate itself

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alarm" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
}
```

Comment: the text to be displayed in the alert is in a textfield of another view controller.I already used this example in another app which worked fine.i dont understand where i went wrong in this app.

Comment: Check `self.setting` is nil or not?? you are taking reminderText from `notification.userInfo`? then you can display the alert in the  `didReceiveLocalNotification:`  right?